# Call Tracing Windows Driver

Tags: c, kernel, driver, trace, stack-trace

I wish to be able to record, in real time, the activity of a kernel mode driver (I have the full symbols for it). It's a HID miniclass driver. I wish to record the execution of calls in this driver (stacktraces every time an IRP enters and leaves the driver).

Is this possible (maybe with EWT and/or WPT)?

Comment: Do you want to trace the IRPs from within your driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about ETW tracing? MS uses it all over inside windows. It will give you call-stacks also.

Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163437.aspx)

Comment: ETW tracing seems to be what I want, but the complexity requires a SMP brain to use it effectively. I finished that project long time ago, but I should learn to use ETW for my current projects!

Comment: I have been using ETW for some of the code I write and I have seen great benefits of using it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to monitor only IRPs you can use [Irp Tracker utility](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=199).

Comment: Not really what I want, but this seems to be an awesome tool. Very useful, thanks! Too bad it seems to be 32 bit only.